# Summernote add text from dropdown at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, summernote

I have a custom button in summernote that has a dropdown of items "one", "two", "three" when I click on for example the text "one" the text is added at the start which is fine. But then when I click on "two" afterwards the text is also added at the start which produces this result.

```
twoone
```

I would like to have the following result

```
one
two
```

Update when I use this line

```
context.invoke("editor.pasteHTML", context.modules.editor.$editable[0].innerText ? "<br>" + $(this).html() : $(this).html() );
```

instead of

```
context.invoke('editor.insertText', $(this).html());
```

I get the following result wihch is better but the order is still incorrect

```
two
one
```

Here you can fiddle with my code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-summernote-demo-n7xn2n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Otherwise here is my code for the button that inserts the text

```
function customButtonGenerator(lstQuoteComments, title) {
  return function (context) {
    const ui = ($ as any).summernote.ui;

    var i;
    var listHtml = '';
    for (i = 0; i < lstQuoteComments.length; i++) {
      listHtml += '<li>' + lstQuoteComments[i] + '</li>';
    }

    const button = ui.buttonGroup([
      ui.button({
        className: 'dropdown-toggle',
        contents:
          '<i class="fa fa-comments text-primary"/><span id="summernot-caret" class="caret text-primary"></span>',
        //tooltip: 'Comments', //Not working when howver over it top is not defined
        data: {
          toggle: 'dropdown',
        },
      }),
      ui.dropdown({
        className: 'drop-default summernote-list',
        contents:
          '<div id="container-comentario"><div id="dialog" title="' +
          title +
          '" ><h1 class="header-comentario">' +
          title +
          '</h1><ul id="summernote-list"><ul>' +
          listHtml +
          '</ul></div></div>',
        callback: function ($dropdown) {
          $dropdown.find('li').each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
              context.invoke('editor.insertText', $(this).html());
            });
          });
        },
      }),
    ]);
    return button.render();
  };
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, these answer don't quite get the question right.

You should append the button content to the existing content like this:

Example blitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-summernote-demo-ycvten?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Main code snippet:

```
...
callback: function ($dropdown) {
  $dropdown.find('li').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
      let newHtml = context.modules.editor.$editable[0].innerHTML
      if (newHtml !== '') {
        newHtml += '<br>'
      }
      newHtml += $(this).html()
      context.invoke('code', newHtml)
    })
  })
}
...
```

I'll have a look if there is a way to keep track of the current cursor position, I think there must be. I'l update if that's possible, rather than just adding to the end.

Comment: Use cursor position would be great too. It would be awsome if you could but It was not my question so I have approved you anwser. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can, using https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#range--selection-api. However, in this instance it requires keeping track of a lot of the nodes (eg so you can highlight bold text etc). But it is out of scope of this question

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace this line in `customButtonGenerator` function:

```
context.invoke('editor.insertText', $(this).html());
```

With:

```
context.invoke('editor.pasteHTML', $(this).html());
```

OR

```
context.invoke('editor.pasteHTML', '<div>' + $(this).html() + '</div>');
```

Comment: Thank you for you help it now adds a space between the words wich is better. However I would like the text to be added at the end so for example whe I click on "one" and then "two" the result should be One Two not Two One

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
context.invoke('editor.insertText', $(this).html());
```

with

```
context.invoke("code",  context.modules.editor.$editable[0].innerHTML + '<br>' + $(this).html());
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for you help it now adds a enter space between the words wich is much better. However I would like the text to be added at the end so for example whe I click on "one" and then "two" the result should be One Two not Two One.

Comment: changed the code a bit. check now.

Comment: Thank you for your help unfortunately it doesn't work. It still insert the text in the top https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-summernote-demo-n7xn2n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: changed the code a little. check now.

Comment: Yes it works now thank very much for you for your help. I wish I could approve your question as well but @dangarfield alredy provided a solution that also works. and is easier to work with.